# Column Bootstrap in while loop PHP

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have this problem
[image]
and that code is here

```html
<div class="col-md-4 text-center animate-box">
                    <a href="work-single.html" class="work" style="background-image: url(images/portfolio-2.jpg);">
                        <div class="desc">
                            <h3>Project Name</h3>
                            <span>Brading</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center animate-box">
                    <a href="work-single.html" class="work" style="background-image: url(images/portfolio-2.jpg);">
                        <div class="desc">
                            <h3>Project Name</h3>
                            <span>Brading</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 text-center animate-box">
                    <a href="work-single.html" class="work" style="background-image: url(images/portfolio-2.jpg);">
                        <div class="desc">
                            <h3>Project Name</h3>
                            <span>Brading</span>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

now i tried to do a while loop for my php and did this code

```
<div class="row">
            <?php
                    while ($userRow=$stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                    {
                        echo "<div class='col-md-4 text-center animate-box'>";
                        echo "<a href='work-single.html' class='work' style='background-image:url(uploaded_files/uploaded_files_articles_images/" .$userRow['image']. ")';";
                        echo "<div class='desc'>";
                        echo "<h3>Project Name</h3>";
                        echo "<span>Illustration</span>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</a>";
                        echo"</div>";
                    }
                ?>
      </div>
```

and it got me this

[image]

So what i tried so far is this

```
<?php
                    while ($userRow=$stmt2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
                    {
<?
                        <div class='col-md-4 text-center animate-box'>
<?php
                        echo "<a href='work-single.html' class='work' style='background-image:url(uploaded_files/uploaded_files_articles_images/" .$userRow['image']. ")';";
                        echo "<div class='desc'>";
                        echo "<h3>Project Name</h3>";
                        echo "<span>Illustration</span>";
                        echo "</div>";
                        echo "</a>";
                 <?
</div>
                        <?php
                    }
                ?>
```

but still not working still the same layout . sorry for my bad english . Can someone help me to figure out what is the problem on my code. Thank you everyone in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo "<a href='work-single.html' class='work' style='background-image:url(uploaded_files/uploaded_files_articles_images/" .$userRow['image']. ")';";`

You are missing a `>` at the end.

Comment: No problem, happens to the best :P

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a `>` in your anchor tag and also misplaced the semicolon of the CSS. Replace your code with the following one.

`echo "<a href='work-single.html' class='work' style='background-image:url(uploaded_files/uploaded_files_articles_images/" .$userRow['image']. ");'>";`